# Why is mapping for spring data solr slow?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

Say I have the following class for solrdocument

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName="some_core")
public class SolrProduct {
    @Id
    @Indexed(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Indexed(name="title_str")
    private String title;

    ....
```

and in the data access layer, code is simply

```
public interface ProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository <SolrProduct, Long> {

    public Page<SolrProduct> findByTitle(String title, Pageable page);

    public List<SolrProduct> findByTitle(String title);

}
```

In the service layer, when I call

```
productService.findByTitle("computer", new PageRequest(0, 10));
```

This is fine since I am only getting 10 results back. However, if i call

```
productService.findByTitle("computer");
```

It takes more than a minute to load since there is 10,000+ solr products with the `computer` title.

There are a lot of other fields that exist from the solr data which don't exist in the solrdocument POJO class I created, so I am guessing the mapping of fields takes some time. Is this correct? or it is simply caused by loading a lot of data during the call? Is there any way I can speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you have many fields stored in solr document, but only a small subset is mapped to java document?
If s, you can limit fileds, that are returned from solr:

```
query.addProjectionOnField("myfield1");
....
query.addProjectionOnField("myfieldn");
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/query/SimpleQuery.html#addProjectionOnField-org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Field-)

This should save data transferred from server, not sure about speed up of mapping.